# Rails + Devise: Wrong Sign out message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, message

I use Devise to perform authentication for my application, and everything is ok, except the Devise logout message which is detected as unauthentication failure:

`en.devise.failure.unauthenticated:
" You need to sign in or sign up before continuing "`

I mean that I have this message when I log out, and not the "Signed out successfully" message.

Maybe I wrongly personnalized my Devise system. Here are the personnalisations I made:

1/ I used my own session controllers to override the default Devise session controller. My only objective, is to choose a special access (login/signup) layout:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

    layout 'access'

end
```

No more code. I only wanted to render using a special login/signup design, located in `views/layouts/access.html.haml`.

Of course, I added this to my `routes.rb` file:

```
devise_for :users, :controller => { :sessions => 'sessions' }
```

2/ I choosed another language for Devise (french), so I downloaded `devise.fr.yml` and pasted it in `config/locales/` folder, and set `config.i18n.default_locale = :fr` in `config/application.rb` file

**All other Devise action messages are correct. Only "Sign Out" have trouble. Any idea?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show me the code of your sign out link?

Comment: I use `link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => 'destroy'` to generate a link with `href = localhost:3000/users/sign_out`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like there's a way to handle custom layouts for devise without inheriting the sessions controller. Take a look at this documentation:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Create-custom-layouts

EDIT

To redirect users back to the sign in page after they sign out add this to your application controller:

```
def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  sign_ins_path
end
```

Comment: Thanks Tom for the answer and the link. I changed code to not override the Devise controllers, but I still have the same problem... Even if I go back to English language!!!

Comment: Maybe what's happening is that the redirect after signing out is going to a restricted controller action. By default Devise redirects to root_path. Is there a `before_filter :restrict_user` in that controller?

Comment: Indeed! My root path is the company dashboard, which contains a `before_filter :restrict_user` in case the user doesn't login or session expires. How can I change the :root path to set it as the login page?

Comment: I wouldn't change the root_path. That could impact other parts of your application. Just redirect the user back to the sign in page. See my EDIT above.

Comment: Of course, it would be typically be new_user_session_path, and not sign_ins_path. But otherwise, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Devise uses an http DELETE request for sign out requests. Make sure you sign out with this link. `<%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>`

Comment: Thanks Luis, but I still have the same wrong log out message. I changed the 'destroy' method (as written in my comment) to 'delete', but no good news!